# Complex Analysis books for Physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, mathematics, complex-numbers, analyticity

I am now in my 6th semester of my physics bachelor and now I'm searching for a complex analysis book.
It shouldn't be too long and deep and not too "mathematical" (I don't need every proof). Applications (preferable in physics) would also be great.
Many illustrations for visual understanding would also be perfect

Answer (score 0):

**A Course in Complex Analysis by S.Zakeri.**

This is a comprehensive graduate-level textbookthat covers all the main topics of classical theory and many elegant developments that are not commonly found in textbooks at this level. It has more than 350 problems, numerous examples, and many illustrations for visual understanding. It also explores the applications of complex analysis in physics and engineering.

**Analysis and Mathematical Physics edited by B.Gustafsson and A.Vasil’ev.**

This is a collection of papers that present recent advances in complex and potential analysis and their applications in mathematical physics. It covers topics such as Laplacian growth models, gravitational lensing, scattering theory, conformal metrics, and uniformization theorem.